# Responsive Google Map

Tags: css, google-maps, responsive

I have a Google Map floating to the right of my contact form. In mobile, it responds by moving above my form, but it is still too large to fit the mobile screen. I've tried some js solutions but nothing has worked. Any ideas?

```
HTML:
       <figure class="showRight"><div id="map">

                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2800.5924582913617!2d-116.31889528431363!3d45.41755717910039!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54a6c56be892013d%3A0xf34792f82bc2a30b!2s1000+Main+St%2C+Riggins%2C+ID+83549!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1500064488028" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                <p class="contactinfo">
                    <strong>SALMON RIVER ADVENTURES</strong><br>
                    1000 S. Main Street<br>Riggins, ID 83549<br>
                    888-888-8888<br>
                </p>
              <h3>Please call us if you have questions.</h3>
               </div></figure>

CSS: 
/* GOOGLE MAP */

#map{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.showRight{float: right; margin 0 2%; }
```

Comment: Try `#map {max-width: 100vw}` or add a link to your site if it's live.

Comment: I tried adding #map {max-width: 100vw} but it did not respond. Site is not live yet.

Comment: Thank you I haz kode!!  I had to let go of having it float right of the contact form. When I did, your suggestion of max-width... worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Tanja

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your current layout makes it a little bit tricky to display things correctly.

I would simplify things a little bit.

I added my comments to the code.

The take away is to use [display:flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Working Example:**

```css
#map_wrapper, #sideBar {
  width: 350px; /* Set the desired width for each the map and the sidebar */
  height: 400px; /* Set the desired height for each the map and the sidebar */
  background: #131418; /* optional */
}

.main {
  max-width: 700px; /* Set the desired max-width for the entire container*/
  display: flex; /* magic */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* even more important magic! This will make the map go to the next line if the screen is not big enough */
}

.main,
#sideBar,
#map_wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto; /* Makes items go in the center of the page if they wrap to the next line */
}


/* The rest of the CSS is for styling only */ 
.main input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main fieldset {
  margin: 4.5em .5em;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<!-- initilize map -->
<script>
  function initMap() {var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {center: {lat: 40.674,lng: -73.945},zoom: 12,})}
</script>


<!--Map setup -->
<div class="main">

  <div id="sideBar">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>How Can We Help You?</legend>
      <div><label><span>Full Name:</span><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Last" pattern="[A-z\s]{3,99}" required="" autofocus="" title="Please provide your full name (minimum of 3 characters)"></label></div>
      <div><label><span>Email:</span><input name="email" type="email" placeholder="user@gmail.com" required="" title="Please provide a valid email address"></label></div>
      <div><label><span>Phone:</span><input name="phone" type="tel" required="" title="Please provide a valid phone number"></label></div>
      <div><label><span>Arrival Date:</span><input name="date" type="date"></label></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>


  <div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
  </div>

</div>



<!-- Load google API in the footer. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHu4QBgWONqtdOWVLTW5XZ51B1eOU6SWw&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```